# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and if both $H$ and $G/H$ are abelian, is $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Pretty straightforward:

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and if both $H$ and $G/H$ are abelian, is $G$ abelian?

Comment: As Zev shows, the answer is no. "Solvable" is a generalization of "abelian", and one of the facts about solvable groups, crucial in Galois Theory, is that the answer is "yes" if you replace both occurrences of "abelian" with "solvable".

Comment: Groups with the property you describe are called "metabelian" (be careful, though, when reading old papers/books; for a while, especially in Eastern Europe, "metabelian" meant a stronger condition that the commutator subgroup be central).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, consider $G=S_3$ and $H=A_3=\{e,(123),(132)\}$. Then $H\triangleleft G$, and $H\cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $G/H\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are both abelian, but $G$ is not abelian.

Comment: Very nice counterexample, thank you.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar I was going to right away, but the 15 minute grace period forced me to wait, and it slipped my mind. :)

Answer (score 4):

As a more general class of examples, consider the group $D_n$ of symmetries on a regular $n$-gon for $n\geq 3$ (of course $D_3 \cong S_3$, so we're really only interested in $n>3$).  Let $R$ denote the element of $D_n$ corresponding to a counter-clockwise rotation of $2\pi/n$, and let $H$ be the subgroup of $D_n$ generated by $R$.  Then $H \triangleleft D_n$ (since $\vert D_n\,:\,H\vert=2$), and clearly both $H$ and $D_n/H\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ are abelian.  However, $D_n$ is not abelian.

Comment: Even more general : if $H$ is any abelian group, and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is coprime to $|H|$, then $f : g \mapsto g^a$ is a group automorphism of $H$ of finite order (the order of $a$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/|H|\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$). Consider the semi-direct product $G = H \rtimes \langle f \rangle$. Then $H$ is normal in $G$, and $G/H$ is abelian. If you take $H = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $a = -1$, you find $G \simeq D_n$.